# Distorted display output from AMD machine

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, lightdm, amd-graphics

So I have a "portable" install of 14.04 (I installed the full distro on a USB3 stick) and I'm having the strangest driver corruption/bug:

[image]

As you can see, anything that uses its own renderer (I assume) isn't affected, but everything else gets the corruption. The only way to fix this is to somehow restart lightdm (reboot, relog, service restart, etc). This happens on both of the computers I plug my drive into, one of which is an AMD machine and the other is an NVIDIA machine (I install the appropriate drivers whenever  I switch machines). I found that the more I use the virtual desktop switching, the faster this happens.

Please let me know if you have any idea or need more information about my rig.

Answer (score 3):

So after a day of messing with it I found what seems to be a pretty simple solution:

1. use `sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia.*' 'fglrx.*' && sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove all traces of both sets of drivers from your system (or pick one if you only have one set).
2. remove your`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (back it up first).
3. Use the driver manager to select the recommended version of your driver (was nvidia-331 for me at the time of writing) and install it.
4. reboot.

Trying to install the drivers from the command line seems to be a bad idea as it misses a few pieces here and there, doing it through the manager on the other hand, seems to get everything you need (I have yet to have a crash or any corruption).

I will see how this holds up on my AMD machine in a few days.